# Configuration profiles in EJB 3+

Tags: configuration, annotations, ejb, ejb-3.1

With Spring there is the concept of Profile annotations...

which are great when one wants to build up components for development/test apart from production setups.  How do people handle this in EJB 3+?

Seen in [http://www.amazon.com/Real-World-Java-Patterns-Rethinking-Practices/dp/1300149310](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1300149310) that CDI injection can be used (i.e. Logger Injection).  Basically one creates a Configuration class that produces settings that are injected into other classes that produce (@Alternative classes) based of these settings.  Not as smooth as Spring profiles but would work.

Any other ways in EJB/CDI?

Comment: Ran across CDI extensions.  Might be a way to "recreate" from the Spring active profile logic.

Comment: Anyone "intercepted" the @Inject to override the resolution of the bean to be injected?  Given a predefined annotation on the bean, say @Profile("development") or @Profile("production"), duplicates could be resolved just like in Spring via a configuration container.

Comment: Something like a beforeBeanDiscovery to register beans part of a @Configuration object based off what profiles are active?